# Disable password suggestions in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

So, basically I'm learning Django from some courses and I was trying to test my registration template. It works fine, but the problem is that I want to disable the password suggestions below the password field. They look like this:

[image: password hints I want to turn off]

I'm using a form which inherits from `UserCreationForm` called `CreateUserForm`, which looks like this:
[image]

So my question is - Is there any function command available in Django to make these hints dissappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are error messages from the default password validators you've set up in your settings.

If you don't want to validate your passwords, you can empty the `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` (IIRC) configuration in your settings; if you don't want to show those messages but quietly validate anyway, it will take either some template hacking or view hacking to erase the error messages.

Comment: Thanks, worked well for me - it was more curiosity than a problem, but your answer really helped me!